# Exercise on product of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $\{x_n\}$, $\{y_n\}$, $\{z_n\}$ are sequences of complex numbers such that:

1. $nz_n=x_n+y_n$ for every $n$;
2. $\lim_{n \to +\infty}x_n=\lim_{n \to +\infty}z_n=0$;
3. $y_n$ has a modulus independent of $n$ (ie $|y_n|=M$ for every $n$) ;

Since every convergent sequence is bounded, from 1. and 3. we have that $\{nz_n\}$ is bounded. My question is the following:

> Does $\{n^{1+\epsilon}z_n\}$ becomes unbounded as $n\to +\infty$ for every  $\epsilon>0$?

Any hint would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $M>0$ we get $|nz_n| >M-|x_n|>\frac M 2$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Hence $n^{1+\epsilon} |z_n| \to \infty$.